# Why is this verifyToken function never getting called?

Tags: node.js, token, verify

Here's my auth.mjs code:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'; 

export function generateToken(userInfo){
    if(!userInfo) {
        return null;
    }
    
    const payload = { username: userInfo.username, exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 30}; 
    const secret = Buffer.from(process.env.JWT_SECRET).toString('base64');

    return jwt.sign(payload, secret, {algorithm: 'HS512'});
    
}

export async function verifyTokens(username, token) {
    console.error("Still inside verifyTokens");
    try{
        console.error('Inside verifyToken');
        const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            jwt.verify(token, Buffer.from(process.env.JWT_SECRET.toString('base64'), {algorithm: 'HS512'}, (err, decoded) => {
               if (err) {
                   reject (err);
               } else {
                   resolve(decoded);
               }
            })
        )})
        
            if (response.username !== username) {
                console.error('response.username !== username');
                return {
                    verified: false,
                    message: 'invalid user'
                }
            }
            
            console.error('response.username === username');
            
            return {
                verified: true,
                message: 'verified'
            }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Verified Tokens Error: ' + error);
        throw {
            verified: false,
            message: 'invalid token'
        }
    }
    
}


export default generateToken;
```

Here's my verify.mjs code:

```
import buildResponse from '../utils/util.mjs';
import verifyTokens from '../utils/auth.mjs';


export async function verify(requestBody) {
    if(!requestBody.user || !requestBody.user.username || !requestBody.token) {
        return buildResponse(401, {
            verified: false,
            message: 'incorrect request body'
        })
    }
    
    const user = requestBody.user;
    const token = requestBody.token;
    try {
        console.error("Verifying this token=" + token);
        console.error("Verifying this user.username=" + user.username);
        const verification = await verifyTokens(user.username, token);
        console.error('Are we verified? verification.verified=', verification.verified);
        if(!verification.verified) {
            console.error("We are NOT verified! verification.verified=", verification.verified)
            return await buildResponse(401, verification);
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error("Error: ", error);
    }
   
    return buildResponse(200, {
        verified: true,
        message: 'success',
        user: user,
        token: token
    })
}

export default verify;
```

The log files show that I get to "Verifying this token" and "Verifying this user.username", but the log files never show the "Still inside verifyTokens" so I don't think it's calling this line.

```
const verification = await verifyTokens(user.username, token);
```

[image]

Comment: `verifyTokens` is not your default export, import it as a named export `import { verifyTokens } from '...'` - could you give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**:

As per [MSN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#description):

> Every module can have two different types of export, ***named*** export and ***default*** export. You can have multiple named exports per module but only one default export.

You are already exporting multiple named exports such as `generateToken` and `verifyTokens` within your `auth.mjs` using [Export Declarations](https://javascript.info/import-export#export-before-declarations) when you used this syntax:

```js
export function generateToken(userInfo){
   //...
}

export async function verifyTokens(username, token) {
   //...
}
```

This means it can be confusing to also use `export defualt` syntax like you have done here in the same file:

```js
export default generateToken;
```

Typically, using `export defualt` is for when you want to [export a single variable, function or class](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/ES6_for_Humans/f4otDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=a+single+variable,+function,+or+class+can+be+specified+as+the+default&pg=PA68&printsec=frontcover). The knock-on effect in your code means that when you do this:

```js
import verifyTokens from '../utils/auth.mjs';
```

The `verifyTokens` variable you just created now actually points to the `generateToken` function because you're now importing the `default` (which was `generateToken`). This is import to understand because when you try to execute `verifyTokens()` here:

```js
const verification = await verifyTokens(user.username, token);
console.error('Are we verified? verification.verified=', verification.verified);
```

What actually happened was this:

```js
const verification = await generateToken(user.username, token); //< token was ignored becuase generateToken only takes one parameter
console.error('Are we verified? verification.verified=', verification.verified); //< verification.verified is undefined
```

**Solution**:

Simply import `verifyTokens` as one of the named exports using curly braces like so:

```js
import { verifyTokens } from '../utils/auth.mjs';
```

Answer (score 1):

In your file `auth.mjs` the default export is `generateToken`:

```
export function generateToken(userInfo) { /* ... */ }
export async function verifyTokens(username, token) { /* ... */ }

export default generateToken;
```

In your file `verify.mjs` you are not importing `verifyTokens`:

```
import buildResponse from '../utils/util.mjs';
import verifyTokens from '../utils/auth.mjs'; // wrong

export async function verify(requestBody) {
  const verification = await verifyTokens(user.username, token);
}

export default verify;
```

You are just importimg the default export from `auth.mjs` and this is not `verifyTokens`, this is `generateToken`.

Unfortunately you don't have any console output in the `generateToken` method, otherwise you would have seen this yourself.

You are trying to import the default export `generateToken` from `auth.mjs`. Therefore, you should import `verifyTokens` as a named export in your `verify.mjs`:

```
import buildResponse from '../utils/util.mjs';
import { verifyTokens } from '../utils/auth.mjs'; // correct

export async function verify(requestBody) {
  const verification = await verifyTokens(user.username, token);
}
```

Or change your default export in `auth.mjs` ;)